# How can I load the Test Configuration for a Test Result using the Azure DevOps .Net Client Libraries

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I can get the test result for the test case but the Configuration is returned as a "ShallowReference" so I only get the Id for it. I can't find any method to search for a Test Configuration however. I can see how to do it in the REST API. Thanks

You can see below - the test Configuration.Name is always blank. This worked previously with the GetTestRunsAsync but that seems to be no longer available

```
            var testCaseResults = _httpClient.GetTestResultsByQueryAsync(testQuery, Project,true).Result;
            
            if (testCaseResults.Results.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Test case {0} not found in project {1}", testCaseId, Project));

            //Just get the latest result
            var topResult = testCaseResults.Results.OrderByDescending(i => i.CompletedDate).FirstOrDefault();

            var output = new TestResult
            {
                RunBy = topResult.RunBy.DisplayName,
                LatestResult = topResult.Outcome,
                StartedDate = topResult.StartedDate,
                CompletedDate = topResult.CompletedDate,
                Configuration = topResult.Configuration.Name
            };
```